Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core
Recently upgraded my application to .NET 8.0.
Getting below error in Azure pipeline.
##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet' failed with exit code 2
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which is currently lts. Unless you have locked down an SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. 

##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ '' ]

I have already added task to YAML for .NET SDK 8.0.302 and .NET Core runtime 8.0.6 which are successful and after that encountering this error. What is going wrong in pipeline?
YAML :
steps:
          - task: UseDotNet@2
            displayName: 'Install .NET Core runtime'
            inputs:
              packageType: "runtime"
              version: "8.0.6"
          - task: UseDotNet@2
            displayName: "Using DotNet@2"
            inputs:
              packageType: "sdk"
              version: "8.0.302"
          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: "Install dotnet format"
            inputs:
              command: "custom"
              custom: "tool"
              arguments: "update -g dotnet-format"
          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: "Lint dotnet"
            inputs:
              command: "custom"
              custom: "format"
              arguments: "--verify-no-changes --verbosity diagnostic"
              workingDirectory: backend

Detailed error message is shown below :
Azure Pipeline Error


Please share your yaml file used to build the pipeline. 2. Add a variable system.debug and set the value to true, then trigger the pipeline to check if there is any detailed error message. And share the detailed error. 3. "Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain ..." isn't the error message but just a message from the MS-hosted agent, which also can be seen in a successful run.


@ZiyangLiu-MSFT Thanks for your response. Updated question with all requested details.

Hi @Stack Overflow, I can reproduce your issue using your yaml file. Please add parameter projects to all your DotNetCoreCLI@2 tasks. See my answer below for the details.

@StackOverflow The exit code 2 should be an expected behavior when using dotnet format command. But in Azure Pipeline, all non zero exit code will be read as error. To solve this issue, you can change to use PowerShell task to run the dotnet format command and set ignoreLASTEXITCODE to true For more detailed info, you can refer to my answer.

I can reproduce the same issue when using the dotnet format command.

Refer to this doc about dotnet format: dotnet format

--verify-no-changes


Verifies that no formatting changes would be performed. Terminates with a non zero exit code if any files would have been formatted.

This is an expected behavior when using dotnet format command. When the command do any changes to the files, it will return a non zero exit code. But the Pipeline will read the exit code as error and fail the task.
To ignore this expected exit code, you can change to use PowerShell task to run the dotnet format command. Then you can set the ignoreLASTEXITCODE to true to ignore the non zero exit code.
For example:
steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET Core runtime'
  inputs:
    packageType: "runtime"
    version: "8.0.6"
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: "Using DotNet@2"
  inputs:
    packageType: "sdk"
    version: "8.0.302"
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Install dotnet format"
  inputs:
    command: "custom"
    custom: "tool"
    arguments: "update -g dotnet-format"

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'dotnet format --verify-no-changes --verbosity diagnostic'
    ignoreLASTEXITCODE: true
    pwsh: true 
    workingDirectory: backend

Result:


This was the actual issue. Solution worked as expected. Thanks a lot. You made my day.

According to your yaml, all your DotNetCoreCLI@2 tasks are missing parameter projects, which is used to specify the path to the csproj or sln file(s) to use.
Testing with your yaml, I can reproduce the error:

Please add projects as shown below:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Install dotnet format"
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'update -g dotnet-format'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Lint dotnet"
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    custom: 'format'
    arguments: '--verify-no-changes --verbosity diagnostic'

Result:

